# How do I compare successfully two Strings in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have successfully implemented HashMap for my project and now I am stucked here..

This is my HashMap... and it will extract SQL data and it will be put into The Hashmap...

```
private Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
sql.... extract data ....
while (...) { 
    list.put(string1, string2);
}
```

So.. now I have two strings...

```
a = mike;
b = james;
```

Since it is a synchronized hashmap.. I want to find out how do I do this..

```
if (list.containsKey=a+b)? or if (list.containsValue=a+b)?
if (list.containsKey(a) && list.containsValue(b)) {
     do....
} else {
     do nth...
}
```

i tried to compare two values and i need both to match and be linked to each other.. I try playing around with it but it seems like when it matches one.. it does something.. and it just needs to match one...

but I want mike and james to be found in the list and then it runs.... something.. I printed out the result of list and it shows mike=james.

How do I do this to find out if mike=james then... exist.. else.. does not exist in list..

Comment: "successfully implemented HashMap" please explain

Comment: It is working as intended. Just that, I do not know how to compare or successfully compare key/value synchronized. like mike=james, so how do I make sure that both strings are correct before proceeding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashMap` (or any other `Map`) is more than just 2 lists, or a list of "pairs", it is a mapping from 1 element (the *key*) to another (the *value*).

Your choice of names for your map ("list") suggests that you are thinking of it as though it's just a list, and that is leading you down the wrong path.

You want to see whether string *a* ("mike") is mapped to *b* ("james").

The requires looking up *a* in the map and testing the result against *b*.

You want something like

```
String m = map.get(a)
if( m != null && m.equals(b) ) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Really hard to understand what you are after. If you are searching for a tuple, something like below would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("mike", "james");

    printTupleIfFound(map, "mike", "james");
}

private static void printTupleIfFound(Map<String, String> map, String fst, String snd) {
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals(fst) && entry.getValue().equals(snd)) {
            System.out.println(fst + "," + snd + " is in the map");
        } else {
            System.out.println(fst + "," + snd + " is NOT in the map");
        }
    }

}
```